# ui.bootstrap.carousel is not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

For some reason I am not able to see, my Carousel will not appear. My project requires slightly different implementation than what is [defined here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It should work fine though, I've outlined the details below.

Clicking my  button toggles `openModal`, where I specify my scope as `modal`:

```
openModal() {
    var _this = this;
    this.$uibModal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'components/directives/modals/Modal/Modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalController',
      controllerAs: 'modal',
      size: 'lg',
      }
    });
}
```

In this controller I declare some variables in the constructor:

```
//Carousel Variables
this.active = 0;
this.currIndex = 0;
this.slides = [];
this.addSlide();
```

This calls my controller function `addSlide`:

```
addSlide() {
for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
  this.slides.push({
    image: 'https://unsplash.it/600/300',
    text: ['Getting Started', 'Awesome photograph', 'That is so cool', 'I love that'][this.slides.length % 4],
    id: this.currIndex++
  });
}};
```

HTML

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
    <div uib-carousel active="modal.active" interval="0" no-wrap="false">
      <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in modal.slides" index="modal.slide.id">
        <img ng-src="{{modal.slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide {{modal.slides.id}}</h4>
          <p>{{modal.slides.text}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is the modal opening, but nothing is displayed? Or is the modal not even opening?

Comment: The modal opens fine and displays the other content on the modal. The carousel being the exception.

Comment: If you add a `console.log()` inside `addSlide()` can you verify that's even being called?

Comment: Yes! The object is logged. In fact it appears I am now getting the arrow and indicators but no image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your markup from...

```
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in modal.slides" index="modal.slide.id">
    <img ng-src="{{modal.slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{modal.slides.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{modal.slides.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

...to this...

```
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in modal.slides" index="slide.id">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>">
```

By including the `modal.` in there you are referencing a non-existent `slide` property on the controller when what you really want is to reference the `slide` object in your `ng-repeat`. (You also had `slides` in a couple places where I think you meant `slide`).